# Content doesn't shows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding and I am working on this imaginary landing page to summer everything that I learned. I finished the header section but the problem is that now I want to work on the rest of the page but the content doesn't shows.

The body has overflow-x: hidden; but even if i remove it the content from the html still doesn't shows . Here is the codepen :  https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/LoOoVm?editors=0100

```
 body {
  max-width: 1330px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: What the heck is `<wrapper>`...?

Comment: it was supposed to be a div with the class wrapper

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Please edit you question and use the snippet button to put your code here - links to codepen must be accompanied by the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your header doesn't have any height to it because the carousel slides are absolutely positioned. This is causing your about section to appear behind the other content.

I would make your carousel slides height: 100% and give your header class the height of 100vh. Should fix your issue.

```
.header{
   height:100vh;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 150px 70px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: You where right . I had to dive the carousel track height:100vh; and the sliders the height:100%; . Thank you so much !!